# Can a trigger access the query string?

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.1

I'm thinking about using triggers as a logging mechanism in MySQL (v. 5.1) and therefore I'd like my trigger to get the query string in order to store it in another tabe.

I couldn't find anything like that in the MySQL documentation so I expect the answer to be no – but I still hope that I've overlooked something.

PS: this question is related to [IcarusNM's answer to my question "Log MySQL DB changing queries and users"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7985/log-mysql-db-changing-queries-and-users/8085#8085)

Comment: That's a wild question, the likes of which I have never heard before. +1 for such outside-the-box thinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *I have a working theory (LaForge would say to Capt Picard).*..

Since you are using MySQL 5.1, you have access to the table [**INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/processlist-table.html).

You also have access to the ID of the current process the trigger is running on. The function to get that process ID is [**CONNECTION_ID**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id).

You could try to fish out the query like this:

```
SELECT info FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id = CONNECTION_ID();
```

Keep in mind that the `info` is LONGTEXT:

```
mysql> show create table information_schema.processlist\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: PROCESSLIST
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `PROCESSLIST` (
  `ID` bigint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `USER` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `HOST` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DB` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMAND` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TIME` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `STATE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `INFO` longtext
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Within the trigger, you could use a local variable to hold the query

```
DECLARE original_query VARCHAR(1024);
```

and then capture the query

```
SELECT info INTO original_query FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE id = CONNECTION_ID();
```

Give it a Try !!!

If it works, then

## *Make it so (Capt Picard would quip back to LaForge)*

Comment: Haha, a truly nice solution, wouldn't have thought about that. I couldn't fully test it yet (too small thread stack), but each of the parts work perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: It is very nice, though I am curious on the performance impact of a write-heavy table :)

Comment: I'll use an archive table, I hope that will limit the performace impact

Comment: That should be fine. Keep in mind that the ARCHIVE storage engine has no indexing. Only INSERTs and SELECTs via full table scans are available.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem: I won't access the logs on a regular basis

Comment: I have tried this, but the query I always get is the "SELECT info INTO" query. The `CONNECTION_ID()` does change, but it looks like the current id is always that of the select? Should I try and save the `CONNECTION_ID()` earlier in the process?

Comment: Was having same problem, similar answer here that works for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628640/get-full-mysql-query-string-on-insert-or-update

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS DEBUG_TIGGER;
CREATE TRIGGER DEBUG_TIGGER
AFTER UPDATE ON my_table 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_my_table(query)
    SELECT argument 
    FROM mysql.general_log 
    WHERE thread_id = connection_id()
    ORDER BY event_time DESC 
    LIMIT 5; /*gives last 5 queries(this will help you get idea of what logical path was taken)*/

    INSERT log_my_table
    (query)
    VALUES('-----------------');/*empty place holder*/
END
```

Comment: you can access the previous record using OLD.colName and you can use new updated record using NEW.colName

Comment: example "IF OLD.eventName <> NEW.eventName THEN /*log my query*/"