# Unable to set general log to fifo pipe

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set my general log file to a fifo named pipe and am getting an error

```
$ sudo mkfifo -m 0666 general.fifo

mysql> set global general_log_file='/var/log/mysql/dradis/general.fifo';
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'general_log_file' can't be set to the value of '/var/log/mysql/dradis/general.fifo'

mysql> \! ls -l /var/log/mysql/dradis/general.fifo
prw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Nov 27 14:27 /var/log/mysql/dradis/general.fifo
```

Version I'm running 5.6.20-68.0-log Percona Server.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it should work because the [general_log_file is dynamic (according to the MySQL Documentation)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log_file).

Some six(6) years ago, Joel Hanger answered [How do I output MySQL logs to syslog?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/how-do-i-output-mysql-logs-to-syslog/5106#5106). In his answer, he added it to the my.cnf. Evidently, a mysqld restart would be needed.

In your particular case, you may have to enable the general log first using

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;
```

to initiate a general log with the default name of `hostname`.log.

This will create an open file handle. You may then have to try setting the `general_log_file` with `general_log` on and off. You may also have to run `FLUSH LOGS;` to force the closing and reopening of log file handles.

This answer is just a lazy guess, so try it and see.

Comment: If I try enabling general_log=1 first it still results in the same error.   

In a test instance I was able to get it working with the cnf and restart.  Unfortunately I'm currently wanting this on a mysqld I can't restart at the moment :(

Comment: Set general_log back to 0. This will close the file. Then, try again. Does it still produce the same error ???

Comment: Same error.  Seems like restart is required if you want to use fifo :(

Comment: OK we tried. Make sure you go upvote https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3552/how-do-i-output-mysql-logs-to-syslog/5106#5106.

Comment: What is good here is that your question exposes the fact that configuring a FIFO pipe will not work dynamically.

Comment: One more suggestion: try using fifo (https://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo) instead of mkfifo since the file becomes part of the file system.